# Accessing Yahoo Contacts through OAuth on App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, yahoo-oauth

I have an existing webapp, running in Python on App Engine, in which users can login through open-id using a Yahoo account. Now, once they're signed in, I'd like them to be able to access their Yahoo contacts, through OAuth. I'm working though the Yahoo Python SDK and am just stuck.

I have the consumer key, consumer secret, app ID, and the callback URL is the same page, the use leaves from. Going to the Yahoo login pages seems to work fine and the user comes back to my site with an auth_token and auth_verifier. What do I do with those? Which strings do I need to store for future requests? Is there good sample code anywhere for these kinds of requests? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for **OpenID+Oauth Hybrid protocol**.

**OpenID+OAuth** Hybrid protocol lets web developers combine an OpenID request with an OAuth authentication request.
This extension is useful for web developers who use both OpenID and OAuth, particularly in that it simplifies the process for users by requesting their approval once instead of twice.

> The goal of OAuth is to acquire an
>   access token from Google, which can
>   then be used to exchange user-specific
>   data with a Google service (such as
>   calendar information or an address
>   book). The regular OAuth process is a
>   four-step sequence: (1) ask for a
>   "request" token, (2) ask for the token
>   to be authorized, which triggers user
>   approval, (3) exchange the authorized
>   request token for an "access" token,
>   and (4) use the access token to
>   interact with the user's Google
>   service data. For a more detailed
>   description, see OAuth for Web
>   Applications.
>
> With **OpenID+OAuth**, this sequence
>   remains essentially the same. The
>   difference is that getting an
>   authorized OAuth request token (steps
>   1 and 2) is wrapped up in the OpenID
>   authentication request. In this way,
>   the user can approve login and service
>   access at the same time.

[Here](http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/) a demo and [source code (php)](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/hybrid) of Hybrid protocol using Google.

[Here](http://step2.googlecode.com/svn/spec/openid_oauth_extension/latest/openid_oauth_extension.html) and [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/openid-oauth-guide.html) the Yahoo documentation to combine an OpenID authentication request with the approval of an OAuth request token.

Comment: Actually, what I'm finding is that first time users are fine logging in with their open-id, but get worried about granting access to their info. So syncing with Yahoo contacts is optional once logged in, but I'm trying to keep the OAuth and the login separate.

Comment: @Ritchie I see. In this case, I think you should store on DataStore the Pre-Approved Request Token given you by OpenID flow. With this token you would be able to start the OAuth flow [described here](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html#oauth-accesstoken) starting from step 4; in a nutshell you jump the boring part to get an authorized Request Token required to get the Access Token that grant access to the User Info.

Comment: Thanks. I've got things basically together using the python SDK. For anyone else trying to go through this, and doesn't find the Yahoo documentation very helpful, I recommend check out this sample code http://rocketscience.itteco.org/2009/12/16/importing-yahoo-contacts-in-django/